# Get details based on language using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

My application supporting multiple language,  I want to get offer details based on language id.
This I can take by joining but my challenge is to get default language text if there is no value for selected language.

ie,

My offer title can  have text in two languages.default language is mandatory and offer title should be there.
But sometimes user wont enter offer title in second language,
when user browsing offer list in second language, I want to take offer title from default language because selected language offer title is not there.
How can I do in a single listing query :(

My Table structure given below,

[image]

How I can achieve using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE switch in your SELECT statement, wrapped in a stored procedure for convenience.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_offer(
  IN p_language_id INT,
  IN p_offer_id INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
      FROM Offers o
      JOIN Offer_details od
        ON o.id = od.offers_id
      JOIN languages l
        ON l.id = od.languages.id
      WHERE
        CASE WHEN
          p_language_id IS NOT NULL
         THEN
          p_language_id = l.id
         ELSE
          is_default = TRUE
        END
        AND p_offer_id = o.id
END
```

Then you call it from your app if they have a language id set with `CALL get_offer($lid,$oid)` or if not `CALL get_offer(null,$oid)`